# Resizing Cloud Harddrive

Tags: linux, partition

I recently upgraded the harddrive from 20GB to 50Gb using the web interface of my cloud service.

But df -h:

```
  Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/vda1        20G   19G   47M 100% /
  udev            488M  4.0K  488M   1% /dev
  tmpfs           200M  264K  199M   1% /run
  none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
  none            498M     0  498M   0% /run/shm
  none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Clearly not a 50 GB partition.

fdisk -l gives:

```
Disk /dev/vda: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders, total 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00064eed

 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1   *        2048    41940991    20969472   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders, total 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00064eed
```

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1   *        2048    41940991    20969472   83  Linux

How do i proceed from here to make the partition a 50GB without loosing data.

OS is Ubuntu 12.10.

**Update and "solution"**
After some help from the accepted solution i created mounted a new partition in the remaining 30GB free space and mounted it as my biggest subdirectory, /var:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        20G  7.7G   12G  42% /
udev            487M  4.0K  487M   1% /dev
tmpfs           200M  268K  199M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            498M     0  498M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/vda2        30G   13G   17G  43% /var
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's **only one partition**, do this:

- `fdisk /dev/<drive>`

  - `p` - observe current partitions.
  - `d` - delete entire the partition.
  - `n` - make new primary partition #1. Make sure it spans the whole disk (I've been able to just accept all the defaults)
  - `a` - make that partition bootable again.
  - `p` - make sure it looks like the output of the first print.
  - If needed, use `t` to change the partition type to match first print.
  - **If everything looks right**, `w` to write changes.
- `resize2fs /dev/<drive>1`.

These steps have worked for me every time for VMs on my XenServer cluster.

As always, if there's any really important data, **make sure you have a recent backup**.

Comment: Doesn't the -d delete it? Does that mean lost data?
And to be clear i should run fdisk with all the specified options?

Comment: You **should** be good to go as long as the output of the second print looks the same as the first print - difference being partition size. The data is still there, you're just overwriting the partition table. Things become a bit more complicated if you have multiple partitions or are using LVM.

Comment: Also, from Wikipedia, "When a partition is deleted, its entry is removed from a table and the data is no longer accessible. The data remains on the disk until being overwritten." - http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#section_5

Comment: Also, those weren't command line options I provided. Those are the commands you'd execute "in" fdisk.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps i will try on a random drive first. Would i know i had a LVM, since it is running from some virtualization software i have no clue of how works. At least i know i never installed some, and it is a one partition disk.

Comment: The fdisk output you provided shows that it's type 83. LVM partitions are 8E. You should be good to go.

Comment: I managed to run fdisk as specified, but i was not able to create a new partition bigger than the old one. The range just didn't allow it.

Comment: I asked support, they said was impossible. Bad service i said. Why do they even have that functionality then. Do you know any cloud service provider were resizing of boot drive is possible?

Comment: [`parted`'s `resize`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/resize.html) might be a bit safer in case your partitions are non standard

Comment: I'm personally partial to Amazon Web Services... But if you're not careful with AWS you can either lose your data (you *must* take care of backups diligently with AWS), or you might have an unexpectedly high bill. I really like SoftLayer too.

Comment: @mindthemonkey, depending on your version of `parted`, the `resize` command has either been removed, or does not work on anything but very old ext2 formats.

Comment: Thanks.. We are currently discussing AWS as an alternative (this issue is not the only one and the plans for AWS have only been enforced due to this issue).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an ubuntu-cloud image, it should have the cloud-init package installed by default, which should take care of this for you automatically.

Comment: But what to do when it doesn't?